# Fedex Location Search Request

Tags: web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, fedex

We have integrated Fedex API in a ruby on rails application .

We need nearest drop off locations . We want to filter locations by DANGEROUS_GOODS_SERVICES.

We have checked the fedex locationService pdf file and we found the following xml request format that we are requesting .

**Request**

```
<SearchLocationsRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/locs/v3"> [^]
  <UserCredential>
    <Key>xxxxxxxxxxxx</Key>
    <Password>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</Password>
  </UserCredential>
  <WebAuthenticationDetail/>
  <ClientDetail>
    <AccountNumber>xxxxxxxxx</AccountNumber>
    <MeterNumber>xxxxxxxxxxx</MeterNumber>
    <Region>us</Region>
  </ClientDetail>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>locs</ServiceId>
    <Major>1</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <EffectiveDate>2016-04-13</EffectiveDate>
  <LocationsSearchCriterion>ADDRESS</LocationsSearchCriterion>
  <Address>
    <StreetLines>811 E 1950 N</StreetLines>
    <City>Spanish Fork</City>
    <StateOrProvinceCode/>
    <PostalCode>84660</PostalCode>
    <UrbanizationCode/>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <Residential>0</Residential>
  </Address>
  <PhoneNumber/>
  <GeographicCoordinates/>
  <MultipleMatchesAction>RETURN_ALL</MultipleMatchesAction>
  <SortDetail>
    <Criterion>DISTANCE</Criterion>
    <Order>LOWEST_TO_HIGHEST</Order>
  </SortDetail>
  <Constraints>
    <RadiusDistance>
      <Value>10.0</Value>
      <Units>KM</Units>
    </RadiusDistance>
  </Constraints>
</SearchLocationsRequest>
```

We are not getting any responses for dangerous goods . 
Any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your search radius from 10.0 KM to something like 20.0 KM as it appears that there’s no valid locations within your original radius.  Also, there’s Constraints.RequiredLocationAttributes where you can specifically define ‘DANGEROUS_GOODS_SERVICES’ to only see locations that support that attribute.

**Request**

```
<q0:SearchLocationsRequest>
      <q0:WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <q0:UserCredential>
          <q0:Key>removed</q0:Key>
          <q0:Password>removed</q0:Password>
        </q0:UserCredential>
      </q0:WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <q0:ClientDetail>
        <q0:AccountNumber>removed</q0:AccountNumber>
        <q0:MeterNumber>removed</q0:MeterNumber>
        <q0:Region>US</q0:Region>
      </q0:ClientDetail>
      <q0:Version>
        <q0:ServiceId>locs</q0:ServiceId>
        <q0:Major>3</q0:Major>
        <q0:Intermediate>0</q0:Intermediate>
        <q0:Minor>0</q0:Minor>
      </q0:Version>
      <q0:EffectiveDate>2016-04-13</q0:EffectiveDate>
      <q0:LocationsSearchCriterion>ADDRESS</q0:LocationsSearchCriterion>
      <q0:Address>
        <q0:StreetLines>811 E 1950 N</q0:StreetLines>
        <q0:City>Spanish Fork</q0:City>
        <q0:StateOrProvinceCode/>
        <q0:PostalCode>84660</q0:PostalCode>
        <q0:UrbanizationCode/>
        <q0:CountryCode>US</q0:CountryCode>
        <q0:Residential>true</q0:Residential>
      </q0:Address>
      <q0:PhoneNumber/>
      <q0:GeographicCoordinates/>
      <q0:MultipleMatchesAction>RETURN_ALL</q0:MultipleMatchesAction>
      <q0:SortDetail>
        <q0:Criterion>DISTANCE</q0:Criterion>
        <q0:Order>LOWEST_TO_HIGHEST</q0:Order>
      </q0:SortDetail>
      <q0:Constraints>
        <q0:RadiusDistance>
          <q0:Value>20.0</q0:Value>
          <q0:Units>KM</q0:Units>
        </q0:RadiusDistance>
        <q0:RequiredLocationAttributes>DANGEROUS_GOODS_SERVICES</q0:RequiredLocationAttributes>
      </q0:Constraints>
    </q0:SearchLocationsRequest>
```